# How can I convert a delimited string to a hash table / array using Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I am looking to convert a collection of comma delimited strings that I have as a variable into a hash table / array in Powershell.
For example

$test =
Heading1,Heading2,Heading3
Line1,Line1,Line1
Line2,Line2,Line2

Is there a way I can easily convert this to a hash table or array so that I can easily retrieve all data under Heading3?

Comment: What you have there seem like valid CSV limitted data. You can use `ConvertFrom-Csv` to create a PowerShell object from  it.

Comment: Wow thank you! That worked great. Totally overlooked this.

Answer (score 0):

Variable was already in csv format so just had to use convertto-csv $test to get it into hash table / array format.
Thank you to Olaf in the comments for this answer!